# Forgot a .class?

Tags: java

I'm getting an error on line 4 saying "forgot a .class, probably at the end." Can somebody please tell me what the solution is?

Side note - Java.util has been imported.

```
public double median(int[] arr)
{
    int[] sortedArr = Arrays.sort(arr[]);
    int arrayIndex = 0;
    int halfArrayIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sortedArr.length; i++)
    {
        arrayIndex = i;
    }
    if(arrayIndex % 2 == 0)
    {
        halfArrayIndex = arrayIndex / 2;
        return sortedArr[half];
    }
    else
    {
        halfArrayIndex = arrayIndex / 2;
        return ((double)sortedArr[half + 1] + sortedArr[half]) / 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: `arr[]` makes no sense.

Comment: int[] sortedArr = Arrays.sort(arr[]); why not just int[] sortedArr = Arrays.sort(arr);

Answer (score 3):

This line is incorrect:

```
int[] sortedArr = Arrays.sort(arr[]);
```

It should be:

```
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

Notice that:

- `Arrays.sort()` doesn't return a value
- You must not write `[]` when passing an array as parameter
- When you sort an array, it'll be modified in-place, bear that in mind, because the original array passed as parameter to this method *will be changed* after this method returns, unless you make a copy of it

Comment: Okay! Makes sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: He's correct. When you pass array as argument or parameter you just put the variable and omit the brackets.

Comment: @TheRollerCodster if this answer was useful for you, please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, just click on the check mark to its left ;)